# How to make my spring-boot application with spring-boot-starter-actuator finish after context creation error?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I had my spring-boot application, with spring-boot-starter-web and DataAccessConfig class to configure my DataSource. In case of some errors in beans creation (e.g. wrong password for DataSoure) I got an error and java process exited immediately.

Then I added spring-boot-starter-actuator and it works fine for me and shows correct data in info and health sections. But now in case of some errors in beans creation (e.g. wrong password for DataSoure) spring context isn't created, but java-process continues to be alive.

I would like to find the way to return previous fail-fast logic and exit from java-process after errors in context creation

my pom.xml content

```xml
...
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
...
    <dependencies>
        <!--spring-boot starters-->
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
...

    </dependencies>
```

my application.yml content

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
```

my Application.java

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Error in bean creation example

```
2019-06-17 16:00:13.422 ERROR 18440 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthIndicatorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicatorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthIndicatorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$29a437a3]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getDataSource' defined in class path resource [ru/hflabs/cpc/DataAccessConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'getDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: ORA-01017: неверно имя пользователя/пароль; вход в систему запрещается

2019-06-17 16:00:13.447  INFO 18440 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-06-17 16:00:13.451  WARN 18440 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
2019-06-17 16:00:13.451  WARN 18440 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource$ThreadedCachingBlockSource$BlockReleaser.run(BlockSource.java:329)
2019-06-17 16:00:13.451  WARN 18440 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [InterruptTimer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
2019-06-17 16:00:13.453  WARN 18440 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2019-06-17 16:00:13.465  INFO 18440 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-06-17 16:00:13.477 ERROR 18440 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:157) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at ru.hflabs.cpc.Application.main(Application.java:17) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:125) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthIndicatorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicatorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthIndicatorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$29a437a3]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getDataSource' defined in class path resource [ru/hflabs/cpc/DataAccessConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'getDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: ORA-01017:
```

Here is thread dump for java process which doesn't finish properly

```
2019-06-17 20:16:27
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode):

"RMI TCP Connection(idle)" #22 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000201f0800 nid=0x980 waiting on condition [0x0000000026c7f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x0000000770a6ae30> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
        at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
        at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"JMX server connection timeout 21" #21 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000021b18000 nid=0x6380 in Object.wait() [0x000000002617e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ServerCommunicatorAdmin$Timeout.run(ServerCommunicatorAdmin.java:168)
        - locked <0x00000007714e1aa8> (a [I)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"RMI Scheduler(0)" #20 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000021b17000 nid=0x53e0 waiting on condition [0x000000002607e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x0000000770a7a818> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"RMI TCP Connection(3)-10.0.30.74" #19 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000021b16800 nid=0x6220 runnable [0x0000000025f7d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
        - locked <0x0000000771685690> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:550)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$383/1836843163.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00000007712187a8> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"RMI TCP Accept-0" #18 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000021b15800 nid=0x133c runnable [0x0000000025d7f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
        - locked <0x0000000770a81840> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(LocalRMIServerSocketFactory.java:52)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:400)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:372)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"DestroyJavaVM" #17 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000021b1b800 nid=0x6364 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Catalina-utility-1" #16 prio=1 os_prio=-2 tid=0x0000000021b15000 nid=0x4b58 waiting on condition [0x000000002577e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c2fd21b8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"InterruptTimer" #15 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000021b1b000 nid=0x4674 in Object.wait() [0x000000002547f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x000000076e1c15a0> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
        - locked <0x000000076e1c15a0> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser" #14 daemon prio=4 os_prio=-1 tid=0x0000000021b19800 nid=0x63f0 in Object.wait() [0x000000002537f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x000000076de29a80> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource$ThreadedCachingBlockSource$BlockReleaser)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource$ThreadedCachingBlockSource$BlockReleaser.run(BlockSource.java:329)
        - locked <0x000000076de29a80> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource$ThreadedCachingBlockSource$BlockReleaser)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Timer-0" #13 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000021b18800 nid=0x1b04 in Object.wait() [0x000000002527f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x000000076ddcd180> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
        - locked <0x000000076ddcd180> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001e375800 nid=0x1768 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"C1 CompilerThread2" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001ca55000 nid=0x429c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"C2 CompilerThread1" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001ca04800 nid=0x5b0c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"C2 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001ca01000 nid=0xb54 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c9ff000 nid=0x6044 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c9fe000 nid=0x56f8 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x000000000348d000 nid=0x15a8 in Object.wait() [0x000000001dd6f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000006c24c3850> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
        - locked <0x00000006c24c3850> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x0000000003482000 nid=0x3e9c in Object.wait() [0x000000001dc6f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000006c24c3a08> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
        - locked <0x00000006c24c3a08> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"VM Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001c9c6800 nid=0x4450 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000033a8000 nid=0x2e88 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000033a9800 nid=0x60b0 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000033ab000 nid=0x11a0 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000033ac800 nid=0x3330 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x000000001e3a2000 nid=0x5210 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 1076
```

Comment: Could you post the file where servletEndpointRegistrar is defined?

Comment: I don't have this type of config-file - I think my application uses default settings

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I realized that problem was in DataSourceHealthIndicator. This behavior (java-process continues to be alive) was reproduced only for error in DataSource-bean initialization — java-process exited correctly for errors in others beans initialization.

After I turned off default health checks via setting application property `management.health.defaults.enabled=false` java process exited correctly for error in DataSource-bean initialization too.

Comment: This worked for me as well in a test (`@SpringBootTest`)